# Choose Your Own Adventure (2) in Code Academy?

Tags: javascript

While my code is technically running, nothing I input while testing the game gives me the `else` answer. Can someone take a look at it to give me a clue?

**Here:**

```
var user = prompt("How cool are you?");
var kind = true; 
var smart = true;
var brave = true; 

switch(user) {
case 'Pretty cool':

    var personality = prompt("Are you kind or smart or brave (yes or no)?");

    if(kind || smart || brave) 
    {console.log("Great.");}

    else 
    {console.log("Hmm...");}
    break;


case 'Cooler than ice':

    var personality = prompt("Are you kind and smart and brave (yes or no)?");

    if (kind && smart && brave)
    {console.log("Prove it!");}

    else
    {console.log("Are you serious?");}
    break; 


case 'Not cool at all': 

    var personality = prompt("Are you kind or smart or brave (yes or no)?");

    if (kind || smart || brave)
    {console.log("I'm sure that's not true!");}

    else 
    {console.log("Well, I'm sure you have some good qualities.");}

    break;

default: 
    console.log("Well?"); 
    break; 
};
```

Comment: kind, smart, and brave are always set to true (initialized as true and never get changed) so only the if will be used. I'm assuming based on the personality you want to change one of those to false, then the else will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` from

```
if (kind && smart && brave)
```

to

```
if(personality)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should say something like:

```
var personality = prompt("Are you kind or smart or brave (enter: kind, brave or smart)?");

if(personality == kind ||personality == smart ||personality == brave) 
 {
 console.log("Great.");
 }

else 
 {
 console.log("Hmm...");
 }
 break;
```